# How change style of a div using select options

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change style of a div using select option dropdowns using innerhtml but I haven't a clue how to do it. Below is a simplified version of what i am working on. What code can be added to make this work?

I'm looking for an elegant solution, with as little code as possible. In this example there should be 9 possible combinations, aside from the default.

```
<div id="change">Some Text</div>

<select name="font" id="font">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>

<select name="foreground" id="foreground">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select name="background" id="background">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So if The selected options were Arial, Red and Red you would want the div to show that?

Comment: Where is your own attempt at the JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript is the key. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @George I've tried js code copied and pasted from elsewhere but it doesn't work. I'm not good with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using pure **JavaScript** (without jQuery):

```
var change = document.getElementById('change');

document.getElementById('foreground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.color = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('font').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.fontFamily = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('background').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/bNVxyP).

Comment: i can't make it work on my site. What tags need to enclose the js and does it go in head or body (sorry for my lack of knowledge)

Comment: @VirtualBloke Put the whole code inside a <script></script> tag and add it before the closing </body> tag. If does not work please post your complete code so I can see what is happening.

Comment: @VirtualBloke Cool, I recommend to put your script into a js file instead of have it in the HTML (is a best practice). Please if works accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use jQuery, if it's available to you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#fontList').change(function(){ 
      $('#change').css("font-family", $(this).val());    
  });

  $('#foregroundList').change(function(){ 
      $('#change').css('color', $(this).val());    
  });

  $('#backgroundList').change(function(){ 
      $('#change').css('background-color', $(this).val());    
  });

});
```

Comment: @George Don't you know that JQuery is also Javascript ? He wanted simplified solution, i gave him one.

Comment: @George I really wonder how did you decide that he can't use JQuery in your own. This is a website where you actually learn something. I gave him an answer with different approach. Using this answer is his own choice, not yours. This answer is not wrong nor irrelevant so downvoting this and flaming me only makes you pathetic.

Comment: The problem is this is NOT a javascript question. He doesn't even know jack squat about javascript. I said "don't forget to" to imply that following piece of code works only with JQuery. I knew he would try this without including the library and fail. I actually care about him. Where is your answer, George ? Where did you help him ? All you do is commenting "Who said anything about jQuery?" under JQuery answers.

Comment: So now your problem is with OP, not me. Wow, i can see clearly why you're done. Have a good day.

Comment: @George - get a life.  Seriously.  OP is beyond help, but in general there's nothing wrong with suggesting a jQuery solution, even if not called for.  So many things are so simple with the aid of that tiny little 80KB library that those of us who focus on getting things done for a living have no problem using it, and suggesting it to others.

Comment: @AdamRackis Points made, you win.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified jQuery as a tag. Here is the code with pure JS

```
<div id="change">Some Text</div>
<select name="font" id="font" onchange="changeFont(this.value);">
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
<select name="foreground" id="foreground" onchange="changeForeground(this.value);">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this.value);">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<script>
    var obj = document.getElementById('change');

    function changeFont(val) {
        obj.style.fontFamily = val;
    }

    function changeForeground(val) {
        obj.style.color = val;
    }

    function changeBackground(val) {
        obj.style.backgroundColor = val;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did the first one, but the rest will be the same.

I added an onchange event to the select input:

```
<select name="font" id="font" onchange="change()">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
```

A javascript function that changes the div style based on the input:

```
<script>
function change(){
  var change=document.getElementById('change');

  var font=document.getElementById('font');
  if(font.value == "Arial"){
   change.style.font-family= "Arial";
  }else if(font.value == "Tahoma"){
   change.style.font-family= "Tahoma";
  }else if(font.value == "Georgia"){
   change.style.font-family= "Georgia";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code has several issues: change and font are the same thing, you don't need to retrieve font by id, you have the reference in the this value. Also the if and else are not needed, you can assign to the change property the this.value.

Comment: @ianaya89 there was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

First, I would adjust some things to simplify the coding later ...

```
<select name="font" id="font" class="changeDiv" data-change="font-family">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>

<select name="foreground" id="foreground" class="changeDiv" data-change="color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select name="background" id="background" class="changeDiv" data-change="background-color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

... now, you can connect to the class and process the "change" ...

```
$(".changeDiv").on('change', function() {
  var change = $(this).data("change");
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#divToChange").css(change, value);
});
```

**#divToChange** should, somewhat obviously be the div you are looking to manipulate.

Comment: Amazing ... who didn't say anything about jQuery.  It can also be done without it and this could easily be a template for that.